# How to count the number of the same instances in a column of a data frame in a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-mining

I am trying to count a number of the same ID inside of each sliding window for this data:

```
                           ID  
DATE            
2017-05-17 15:49:51         s_2   
2017-05-17 15:49:52         s_5   
2017-05-17 15:49:55         s_2   
2017-05-17 15:49:56         s_3   
2017-05-17 15:49:58         s_5
2017-05-17 15:49:59         s_5
```

I am trying to count the number of same ID inside rolling window of size 3 which overlap each other. Answer should be like this:

```
DATE                    ID      s_2_count    s_3_count   s_5_count       
2017-05-17 15:49:51     s_2         2            0         1 
2017-05-17 15:49:52     s_5         1            1         1   
2017-05-17 15:49:55     s_2         1            1         1   
2017-05-17 15:49:56     s_3         0            1         2   
2017-05-17 15:49:58     s_5         NaN          NaN       NaN
2017-05-17 15:49:59     s_5         NaN          NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.get_dummies`, `rolling`, `sum`, `shift`, and `add_prefix`:

```
df.ID.str.get_dummies().rolling(3).sum().shift(-2).add_suffix('_count')
```

Output:

```
                     s_2_count  s_3_count  s_5_count
DATE                                                
2017-05-17 15:49:51        2.0        0.0        1.0
2017-05-17 15:49:52        1.0        1.0        1.0
2017-05-17 15:49:55        1.0        1.0        1.0
2017-05-17 15:49:56        0.0        1.0        2.0
2017-05-17 15:49:58        NaN        NaN        NaN
2017-05-17 15:49:59        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Let's assign it back to the dataframe:

```
df.assign(**df.ID.str.get_dummies().rolling(3).sum().shift(-2).add_suffix('_count'))
```

OR using join

```
df.join(df.ID.str.get_dummies().rolling(3).sum().shift(-2).add_suffix('_count'))
```

Output:

```
                      ID  s_2_count  s_3_count  s_5_count
DATE                                                     
2017-05-17 15:49:51  s_2        2.0        0.0        1.0
2017-05-17 15:49:52  s_5        1.0        1.0        1.0
2017-05-17 15:49:55  s_2        1.0        1.0        1.0
2017-05-17 15:49:56  s_3        0.0        1.0        2.0
2017-05-17 15:49:58  s_5        NaN        NaN        NaN
2017-05-17 15:49:59  s_5        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Option 2 using pd.crosstab

```
df.assign(**pd.crosstab(df.index,df.ID).rolling(3).sum().shift(-2))
```

OR use join

```
df.join(pd.crosstab(df.index,df.ID).rolling(3).sum().shift(-2))
```

Comment: @Ali ...and you can reset_index if you would like to get it all in the columns.

Comment: thanks so much! it is a really clever way to do this

Comment: May I ask another question, `**df.ID` or `**pd.crosstab`, are they pointer? Do you have any source I can read about using `**`?

Comment: @Ali  I don't think the ** dictionary unpacking of a dataframe is documented, therefore I updated this solution with join option.

Comment: thanks so much! I understand the code now, but can you briefly explain the `**` notation if you can